# UV unwrapped ico sphere not showing up in UV editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've got an Ico sphere. First I marked the seam:
[image]

Then I Selected the whole thing and UV unwrapped:
[image]

However, when I go into the UV image editor, nothing comes up:
[image]

I'm using cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the `Render Result` image in your UV editor.  Render results don't have texture coordinates.  Use the `Image` menu in the UV editor to load an existing image or create a new image.